# Launching of Spark 1.4.0 EC2 doesn't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

After launched a t2.micro instance with Debian and import my AWS keys, i tried to launch a Spark cluster on Frankfurt server with this command :

`spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/ec2/spark-ec2 -k spark_frankfurt -i spark_frankfurt.pem -s 1 -t t2.micro --region=eu-central-1 --hadoop-major-version=2 launch mycluster`

But it replies me the following answer :

`Setting up security groups...`

`Searching for existing cluster mycluster in region eu-central-1...`

`Could not resolve AMI at:` https://raw.github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/branch-1.3/ami-list/eu-central-1/hvm

Comment: not enough information.
require full logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all the logs i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact Frankfurt, eu-central-1, is not in the AMI list on the official EC2 repository : https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/tree/branch-1.4/ami-list.
Thus it's normal that it doesn't work for the moment.